# Adjoint representation of Hermitian operator is always $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, lie-algebras, hermitian-matrices

Let $H$ be a finite dimensional Hermitian operator in $\mathfrak{gl}(n;\mathbb{C})$ with adjoint representation $\text{ad}_H$. Using the argument presented below, I end up with the result that $\text{ad}_H = 0$ using only the assumption that $H = H^\dagger$, and I am wondering where my error is, given that this is not necessarily true.

- Since $H$ is Hermitian, its eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ are all real. Since the eigenvalues of the adjoint representation are the set of differences $\{\lambda_i - \lambda_j: 1 \leq i,j\leq n\}$ of the eigenvalues of $H$, it follows that the adjoint representation has only real eigenvalues, and is thus Hermitian:
  $$\text{ad}_H = (\text{ad}_H)^\dagger$$
- Second, noting that, for $X \in \mathfrak{gl}(n;\mathbb{C})$, we have $[X^\dagger, \cdot] = -[\cdot, X^\dagger] = -[X,\cdot]^\dagger,$
  it follows that for arbitrary $X$, we have
  $$\text{ad}_{X^\dagger} = -(\text{ad}_X)^\dagger.$$
- Combining the two results above for $H$, we have

$$\text{ad}_H = (\text{ad}_H)^\dagger \quad \text{and} \quad \text{ad}_H = \text{ad}_{H^\dagger} = -(\text{ad}_H)^\dagger,$$

meaning that $\text{ad}_H$ is both Hermitian and anti-Hermitian, and thus, is equal to $0$. This is clearly not necessarily true, so could someone help me identify where the error in my argument is?

Comment: I suppose the daggers are Hermitian adjoint?

Comment: There's a second issue here that should be clarified, I think (aside from what I mention in my answer below): how are you defining the Hermitian structure on $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ with respect to which you take Hermitian adjoints? The usual choice is $(X,Y)=\mathrm{tr}(X Y^\dagger)$, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second bullet point, the second equality seems to be false.

The correct identity is

$$-[\cdot,X^\dagger]=-[X,\cdot^\dagger]^\dagger.$$